# How to integrate TinyMCE button and pass through variables

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need to integrate the TinyMCE and an image upload button dialog with my own webapp – but I need the image upload to post into my PHP code with some custom variables.
My PHP calls the tinyMCE.init with the following activation code:

originating PHP code (that triggers the editor)...

```
<?php

$js='
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "spellchecker,advhr,table,addimg", 
    theme_advanced_buttons1 :     "cut,copy,paste,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,formatselect,zoom, blockquote,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,addimg,|,code,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "tablecontrols,|,spellchecker,advhr,removeformat,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,visualaid",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",      
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    content_css : "'.config::siteurl.'/css/myStyle.css"
});
```

....This activates the editor with a custom button 'addimg'; when I click the addimg custom button it triggers the custom dialog.htm as expected; but what I need is that this dialog.htm contains my variables so that when the form is posted then the receiving PHP can utilise them

dialog.htm form...

```
.
.
.
<form id='file_upload_form' name='file_upload_form' enctype='multipart/form-data'     action='myUploader.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='MySpecialId’ value='xxxx'>
     <table width=100%>
     <tr valign=top>
     <td width=100>Please choose a file: </td>
     <td align=left>
         <input style='width: 100%;'  id='myFile' name='myFile' type='file'>
     </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
</form>
.
.
```

The question is how can I get a value from the original PHP caller into the dialog.htm so to set the MySpecialId value in the form above? I figured I could use Javascript from the dialog.js AddImgDialog.init() js method to set the form but then again how can I get the TinyMCE toolbar to pass through a value from the calling PHP to the custom button dialog.js?

e.g.

```
var AddImgDialog = {
    init : function() {
    alert( 'My passed through value is xxxxx' );
},
.
.
```

Any hints?
Thanks
TD

Answer (score 4):

You may setup your variable in tinyMCE.init() , example:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    /*more settings*/
    myVariable:12345
});
```

This variable will be accessible in dialog.htm via **tinyMCE.settings.myVariable**
To make the input easier reachable give it an ID, e.g. myInputID.
Now you may set the value(place the following instruction somewhere after the input)

```
document.getElementById('myInputID').value=tinyMCE.settings.myVariable;
```